# Need to construct java entites at runtime for XML unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, web-services, maven, jaxb

Conditions: Simple web service receives XML file with some entity in it from some java client.

Task: Marshall this XML with JAXB without an entity class: class should be loaded at client's compile-time.

Example:

```
marshaller.marshall(new Shape(), someShape.xml);
```

There is no class "Shape" in the client app package. It should be loaded at compile-time.

How can I perform that uploading? Project is under Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using maven, check out the maven-jaxb2-plugin.

[Documentation here.](http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home)

You would just add something like this to your pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <generatePackage>com.psed.project.entities</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
```

This will generate all of the entities from your schema files at compile time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its exactly what i'm looking for! Beautiful and simple solution.